# Open ScudCloud from terminal gives Cannot find dictionaries for "/usr/share/hunspell/en_IN" why?

Tags: sharing, 15.10

I open my terminal and type ScudCloud it get started and on the termianl it gives me a message that Cannot find dictionaries for

```
/usr/share/hunspell/en_IN"
```

i don't know why and even don't know what is this for. can any one guide me?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

`sudo apt-get install hunspell-en-us libqtwebkit-qupzillaplugins python3-hunspell`

https://github.com/raelgc/scudcloud/blob/master/README.md